# how to say 2 in the script for the answer automatically

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, centos

I am using

```
sudo --config java
```

to set the java default version:

[image]

as you see in the above I entered 2.

The problem is I call this command in script and I need to say 2 in the script. I tried the following:

```
sudo 2 | alternatives --config java
```

But it does not work. any idea how to do that?

Comment: You may want to see [**update-java-alternatives vs update-alternatives --config java**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java)

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar Hi I put scripting as a tag as well but there wqas no scripting for linux as a tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "2" | sudo alternatives --config java
```

Comment: When I run it in command line it says unable to resolve current working directory. I have not tried it via script yet. Is it supposed not to work in command line and work on script?

Comment: Does `sudo alternatives --config java` work when you provide parameters manually?

Comment: Works for me. Weird. What happens when your try adding `-E` option to `sudo`? `echo "2" | sudo -E alternatives --config java`

Comment: Let me close my session and try it again on server manually and by script that may help. I will let you know about the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending time on my question. it worked sorry I forgot to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo --config java
expect "number: "
send "2\r"
```

Comment: So before I try: should the expect be like this expect "number: " or  this: expect "enter to keep ...number: "

Comment: He's not using `Expect` as far as I can tell. How do you expect those commands to work?